# Windows 7 WriteFile on com port access denied error

Tags: serial-port, access-denied, writefile

Scenario:

1. Windows#7 (fully patched).
2. Com port accessed through win32 api in auto-test application; software dates back to around 2010 (i.e. well established).
3. Com port is FTDI USB to serial converter, never a problem in the past.
4. Auto-test runs for an arbitrary period (minutes up hours); then the WriteFile() starts returning ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED(5); ClearCommError() has no affect; application requires re-start to recover communication port access.
5. Auto-test is typically the only user process running on the PC.

Has anybody come across a similar failure scenario? Thanks in advance for responses.

Comment: That is not possible.  9 out of 10 "I have a weird error" questions at SO are caused by broken error checking.

Comment: The code hasn't changed in literally years and was definitely working, hence broken error checking? I was thinking that a windows update was a more likely cause and was hoping that somebody had seen something similar with an appropriate solution.